# regex sub in python - grouping of characters to identify 3 characters and only change one of them

Tags: python, regex

Im trying to locate the symbol " in a large text when it is immediately preceded and followed by a word or character only. I then want to replace it with this symbol without changing the word/number before and after it: '

I tried this:

```
text7 = re.sub(r'(\w)"(\w)', r"$1\'$2", text6)
```

For the word "it"s" all i get now is i$1'$2. What I want is "it's"
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lookbehind and lookahead; these just look without being modified by the replacement text:

```
text7 = re.sub(r'(?<=\w)"(?=\w)', "'", text6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `\b"\b` replace with `'`. `\b` is a word boundary and matches anywhere the following matches (without consuming characters): `^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W`.

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYuroCgzr0SjKFWvuDRJo0g9JkkpJkldR0FJXUlHQT2zRKlYXVPz/38A)

```
import re
print(re.sub(r'\b"\b', "'", 'it"s'))
```

P.S. In python `\1` or `\g<1>` are used to reference capture groups, not `$1` as it will instead be interpreted literally. See python's [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.sub) documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

For help with the `re` module, I recommend running `help(re)` in your interpreter (or `pydoc re` from the command line). It's laid out really conveniently and I find it easier to follow than the online documentation.

Solution:

```
>>> import re
>>> text6 = 'it"s'
>>> print(re.sub(r'(\w)"(\w)', r"\1'\2", text6))
it's
```

You used `$1` to match group 1, but in Python it's `\1`. Also you had an extra `\` in front of the single-quote in the replacement string.